# Tooltip Styling? (Kick me in the right direction)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this element:

```
 <span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_INSTR$1">
    <a href="WWW.WEBSITE.COM" target="_blank">LEROY JENKINS</a>
 </span>
```

And I want to add a tooltip that looks like this:

```
LEROY JENKINS
-------------
Age: 45
Location: USA
```

Where Leroy is maybe bold/slightly bigger (whatever, I can google the CSS for that). And I have variables ready called 'name' 'age' (the whole string) and 'location' (the whole string) already ready to be popped into a tooltip.

My issue is - to start, where the element is a reference to that whole element (mtg_..) do I just add in the text through a child node and then use CSS to style it? Can someone point me in the right direction because every guide is either too basic/does not have enough information or is way too complicated?

I am willing to do the work myself, I just am not sure where to start basically.

Comment: the normal (small) tooltips are not so good. If you want to do more styling I would suggest to look into bootstraps "popover" here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/awggXO

Comment: @hansTheFranz That's pretty cool, seems like a nice way to seperate the name from the data that matters. I'm friggin brand new to JS/HTML/CSS and working on a project (this) to learn them. Can I style the popover boxes (change colors/etc/probably normal CSS stuff)? And instead of an on-click popover, is there some 'bootstrap' hover equivalent?

Comment: the solution @MichaelCoker just posted looks pretty fly. Would use it.

Comment: I am not smart. .

Comment: It does seem pretty cool. I think for the sake of finishing what I set out to do, I'll look into that bootstrap thing. If I can't figure all that out, it does look cool!

Comment: @Kevin alright, updated the pen to add the element via js https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/awggXO

Comment: @MichaelCoker One improvement: add `visibility:hidden;` to `.tooltip`, and on `:hover` add `visibility:visible;`. That will prevent the flickering when moving the mouse under the link-text, and will also only show the tooltip when hovering over the text in the first place, not underneath it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker **WHY IT WORKS:** `visibility:hidden` hides an element so that you can't interact with it anymore (while still preserving its place on the page). So, where `opacity:0` only makes the element transparent but still hoverable (and clickable etc, interactable), `visibility:hidden` will truly hide the element from all user interaction. **So in your demo** the tooltip would be hidden and therefor not react to *:hover* (underneath the text-link). Only after *:hover* on its parent element, the tooltip becomes visible (and interactable) and only now the tooltip will react to *:hover*.

Comment: @myfunkyside good idea, though the downsides are the tooltip no longer fades out, and the transition isn't as smooth. Here's an updated pen https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/eRqrvm

Comment: @MichaelCoker I fixed the fading problem, by adding `visibility` to the `transition`, where on the fade-out it has a *transition-delay* that matches the *transition-duration* of the other properties. [See this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqORWL). (I also added `white-space:nowrap;` to the tooltip, so you can use spaces without unintended line breaks.)

Comment: And I actually found a [site that explains the whole thing in detail](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337), if anyone wants more info.

Comment: @myfunkyside brilliant!

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think it's time you officially posted this as an answer, people need to find this very concise and elegant solution more easily:)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element to your existing element for the tooltip via javascript, using `innerHTML`. Then absolutely position the tooltip in this element and apply a combination of `opacity` and `visibility` with `transform` and special timing (thanks to @myfunkyside) to have the tooltip fade in from the bottom and appear over your element.

```js
document.getElementById('MTG_INSTR$1').innerHTML += '<span class="tooltip">\
    <div class="title">LEROY JENKINS</div>\
    Age: 45<br>\
    Location: USA\
  </span>';
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;}
body {padding:100px 0 0 50px;}

.PSLONGEDITBOX {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: visibility 0s .25s, opacity .25s, transform .25s;
}
.PSLONGEDITBOX:hover .tooltip, .tooltip:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .25s, transform .25s;
}
.tooltip .title {border-bottom:1px dashed black;}
```

```html
<span class="PSLONGEDITBOX" id="MTG_INSTR$1">
  <a href="WWW.WEBSITE.COM" target="_blank">LEROY JENKINS</a>
</span>
```